# evaluating the integral of sinc function from zero to infinity by shifting the poles instead of deforming the contour.

Tags: integration, limits, contour-integration, residue-calculus

$\int_0^{\infty} {{sin x}\over x} dx$

I Know to do this integral by deforming the contour in a complex plane around $Z=0$.

My question is can we do this integral by shifting the poles (just change the pole location to $x_0+i\epsilon $ or $x_0-i\epsilon $ and give limits $\epsilon$ tends to zero), I tried a lot but my limit diverges.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on what you mean by shifting the poles?

Comment: I edit the question....  if you need I give a  video link which mentions about pole shifting @copper.hat

Answer (score 0):

For $a \in \Bbb{R}^*$ you can evaluate $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i x}}{x+ia}dx$$ with the residue theorem

Taking the complex conjugate it means you know $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-i x}}{x-ia}dx$ and $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x+ia)}{x+ia}dx$$  letting $a\to 0$ you get your result

Comment: How do you know that the integral, as a function of $a$ is continuous at $a=0$?

Comment: There are many ways : Cauchy integral theorem, integration by parts to make it $L^1$ (probably the most natural method because we already use it to show the integral converges), move the contour in $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(x)/x dx$ without "moving the pole"

Comment: I know the result is true, but how does it follow from your answer?

Comment: I don't see what you mean, I didn't write all the details so what ? The residue theorem for $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i x}}{x+ia}dx$ already needs being careful with the limits and integrals, making obvious that the last one is continuous in $a$

Comment: I mean in absence of nice convergence results (dominated convergence, etc.) how do you establish that the limit as $a \to 0$  of the integral is equal to the integral in question? It is not a detail, it is the whole point.

Comment: In contour deformation method we take ${{sin x }\over x}={{e^{ix}}\over {2ix}} $ . I don't get how you write $sin x $ in that form.@reuns

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3409713/contour-integration-with-2-poles-in-scattering-theorey       its a similar doubt  by me

Comment: I studying  QFT .shifting of pole trick is called feyman trick to solve green function .